# How to create custom descriptor (so not with SIFT,SURT) to use with Bag of words in OpenCV?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision, svm, descriptor

is it possible to create a custom descriptor from features compiled with own feature extractor (not SIFT,SURF...) to use with a Bag of words and SVM implementation in OpenCV? So how to set up the Mat descriptor? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you follow the comments you got on answers.opencv.org?

Comment: You can do it in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/image-retrieval-using-customized-bag-of-features.html

Answer (score 0):

In the very first step of the BoW categorization, the descriptors are clustered by kmeans. By default this method uses the L2 norm to cluster the provided data and you are not able to use another norm for kmeans without OpenCV library modification, or without write your own BoW to replace `cv::kmeans`.

But in any case, if L2 norm is fit to your descriptors then you are able to use your own descriptors.